# Jquery tabs: how to link directly to a tab

Tags: jquery, tabs, hyperlink

i got this script: http://www.htmldrive.net/items/show/542/Simple-Tabs-w-CSS-jQuery.html

Now i was wondering: is it possible to create a link to a tab? Something like exemple.com/#tab4

Thanks,
Mariano

Comment: look at `window.location.hash` - you can get the hash value from the url with that and then just set the tab with javascript.  Google can do this for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to detect hash changes with:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function () {

  //your code here...

});
```

Then with `window.location.hash` you'll get the `#hash`, and you can use it to do the same thing as on the click event in your code.

You'll get something like this:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function () {
    hash = window.location.hash;
    if (hash) {
        elem = $('ul.tabs li:has(a[href="'+hash+'"])'); //Select the li targeted
        $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active"); //Remove any "active" class
        elem.addClass("active"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
        $(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
        var activeTab = elem.find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); //Fade in the active content
        return false;
    };
});
```

References:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/hashchange/

http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: it works if i put it in the url and press enter...but why it doesn't work if i put it in a <form action="./#tab2">?

also, when clicking on the tabs the URL doesn't change

Comment: to change the URL when clicking on a tab, you can add this `window.location.hash = activeTab;` after `var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href");` on the `click()` event

Comment: ok, thanks...so why it is not opening at #tabN after the form have been submitted?
also, when refreshing it goes always to tab1 even if in the URL there's another tab specified

Comment: don't know exactly, but I think that the URL is modified when sent with a hashtag, so this `index.html#tab2` will become this `index.html?#tab2` and it'll no longer be a hashtag but a GET parameter.